# How to get a week number from NSDate consistently in all iOS versions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5

I use the following to obtain a week number from an NSDate:

```
[[calendar components: NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:date] week]
```

Unfortunately, I get different values in different iOS versions. Values returned by iOS 4.* and 5 differ by 1. Is there any way to retrieve week number consistently?

Comment: Which is correct?  Please supple a date that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I think every date exhibits the problem. Concrete example: 6th of January 2011 (the first Thursday of the year) gives 2 as week number in iOS 5, but 1 in iOS 4. This suggests iOS 4 might have been using ISO week numbers, while iOS 5 is not.

Answer (score 23):

Since iOS5 NSCalender dosent seem to be defining accordingly to ISO 8601 as default.
You need to set your calender with method "setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek" to get expected week number result.

```
[yourCalender setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek:4];
```

"4" means Thursday in this case.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date
"The first week of a year is the week that contains the first Thursday of the year."

I don't know why it's not defined as "4" as default in iOS5. Just one of those wierd "bugs" i guess ;)

And yes, this will work in both iOS 4 and 5.

Answer (score 7):

iOS5 appears to be wrong, Bug ID# 10412573.

Summary:
    iOS5 NSDateComponents week reports the incorrect week with both NSWeekCalendarUnit and NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit.

Steps to Reproduce:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"week: %i", [[calendar components: NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:date] week]);
NSLog(@"week: %i", [[calendar components: NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date] weekOfYear]);
```

Expected Results:
The same week number on iOS4 and iOS5. For 11/8/2011 the week should be 45.

Actual Results:
The same week number on iOS5. For 11/8/2011 the week should be 46.

Regression:
    iOS4 is correct, iOS5 is incorrect.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the bug? I tried googling and I also searched iOS developer portal, but can't find a way to find the bug report. I would like to follow the bug to see what Apple says.

Comment: Maybe just use an if statement to see if it is iOS 5 and if it is just tack on one more week until the bug is fixed. Of course though you have to be careful though because when they do fix it, it will cause the app to have a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Week numbering is standardized by [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

I bet that iOS5 is correct and that a bug has been filed for iOS4.

A possible solution is to add a workaround that fixes the iOS4 bug.