# What´s the difference between NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit and NSWeekCalendarUnit

Tags: objective-c, ios, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have a NSCalendar:

what´s the Differnece beteween:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents;
dateComponents = [cal components:(NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit ) fromDate: testDate ];
dateComponents = [cal components:(NSWeekCalendarUnit ) fromDate: testDate ];
```

They both return 10 for this week.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are supposed to be the same.

As shown in [How to get a week number from NSDate consistently in all iOS versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037897/how-to-get-a-week-number-from-nsdate-consistently-in-all-ios-versions), there's apparently a bug in iOS 5 where they give different results.